# How to extract HYBAS_ID values from the WWF HydoATLAS Basins feature collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using the HydroATLAS feature collection in Google Earth Engine to work with watersheds in a region of interest. Here is an example:

```
// Load watershed boundaries
var basinATLAS = ee.FeatureCollection('WWF/HydroATLAS/v1/Basins/level07');

// Create polygon for region of interest
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([111.5, -1.0, 113.0, 0.0, 110.0, 0.0]);

// Center map on region of interest
Map.centerObject(region,8)
Map.addLayer(region,{},'ROI')

// Filter only the watersheds related to the region of interest
var watersheds = basinATLAS.filterBounds(region);

// Display watersheds
Map.addLayer(watersheds.style({
  fillColor: '339766',
  color: '000000',
  width: 1}),
  {},
  'Watersheds',
  true,
  0.8
);
```

Now, I want to extract the HYBAS_ID number for each of the watershed polygons. The HYBAS_ID number can be found by running the command `print(watersheds)` in the code editor and clicking on the output in the console. In this example, the `features` dropdown contains a List of 21 elements. By clicking on one of the elements, you can view its properties, and within its properties is the HYBAS_ID number for that polygon.

My question: *How can I extract the HYBAS_ID for each polygon in `watersheds` and print those values as a list?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the list of `HYBAS_ID` in `watersheds`, you simply do this:

```
print(
  watersheds.aggregate_array('HYBAS_ID')
)
```